# Problem with inserting data to custom table using ajax in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to insert data in custom table in wordpress while creating plugin using AJAX. But I failed to do.
here is the code of contact.php where I register scripts

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'setting_up_scripts_contact_form_wp');
function setting_up_scripts_contact_form_wp() {
    wp_register_style( 'contact-custom-style',plugins_url('public/css/style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'contact-custom-style');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cfajax-con', plugins_url('includes/submit-form.js', __FILE__),array(),false,true  );
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'wpforajax_con_test', plugins_url('public/js/test.js', __FILE__) );
    // wp_register_script('wpforajax_con_test', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'test.js', true);
    wp_localize_script(
        'jsforcon-frontend-js',
        'jsforcon_globals',
        [
          'ajax_url'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
          'nonce'       => wp_create_nonce( 'jsforcon_insert_nonce' )
        ]
      );
}
```

contact form is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row display_big justify-content-center">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <form>
           <input type="text" id="conName" class="txt_trans txt_full " name="conName" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
           <input type="text" id="conMail" name="conMail" class="txt_trans txt_full" placeholder="Mail" required><br><br>
           <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted p-0 m-0">We takes your mail id for sending reply to you.</small> 
           <textarea id="conContant" class="txt_a_trans txt_full " name="conContant"cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="content" required></textarea>
           <div class="con_error_msg"></div>
           <button type="button" class="btn_submit" id="saveContact" value="load data" >Contact Us</button><br><br><br><br> 
           </form> 
           </div> </div></div>

<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var ajaxurl = '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."'</script>"; ?>
```

and the insert.php file is here

```
<?php

function my_contact_form(){

require( dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$table_name = 'wp_contact_form';

  $wpdb->insert( 
    $table_name, 
    array( 
        'con_name' => $your_name, 
        'con_main' => $your_mail, 
        'contant' => $your_content, 
        'con_status' => 'unview',
        'con_rep_status' => 'notReplied',
        'con_date' => time()
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
 );
}
?>
```

javascript code for implementing ajax

```
    var cf_saveContact =  document.getElementById("cf_saveContact");
  cf_saveContact.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var conName =  document.getElementById("conName").value;
  var conMail =  document.getElementById("conMail").value;
  var conContant =  document.getElementById("conContant").value;
   
       if(conName == "" || conMail == "" || conContant == ""){
              document.querySelector(".con_error_msg").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>all fields are required</p>";
            }else{
                var action = "jsforcon-insert";
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET",jsforwp_globals.ajax_url+"?action="+action+"&_ajax_nonce="+jsforcon_globals.nonce+"&name="+conName+"&mail="+conMail+"&content="+conContant,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                        conName =  document.getElementById("conName").value = "";
                        conMail =  document.getElementById("conMail").value = "";
                        conContant =  document.getElementById("conContant").value = "";
                        document.querySelector(".con_error_msg").innerHTML = "<p style='color:green'>Successfully Sent</p>";
                    } } }
});
```

I use the ajax code outside wordpress work but in wordpress not works.
I just want to insert data using ajax in wordpress table. If you have any other method than suggest.

Comment: Where is this code currently? Do you check the error logs?

Comment: @Bhautik my code is in the plugin folder and ajax file in plugin/contact/public/js and I declare ajax script in plugin/contact/contact.php

Comment: @Bhautik I think I am wrong in providing the url in ajax call, this ajax code working outside the wordpress

Comment: Please share Javascript code as well.

Comment: @Bhautik sorry, I forgot to share the js code, now I add please see.

Comment: What response did you get? did you get any errors? did you check the error logs?

Comment: @Bhautik now I did some changes, then shows jsforwp_globals.ajax_url is undefined

Comment: Where you did your javascript code.

Comment: @Bhautik plugins/contact/includes/submit-form.js

Comment: Or simply tell me how to add ajax in wordpress plugin using vanilla js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230883/discussion-between-bhautik-and-pankaj-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the wrong handler name to `wp_enqueue_script` for submit-form.js.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'setting_up_scripts_contact_form_wp');
function setting_up_scripts_contact_form_wp() {
    wp_register_style( 'contact-custom-style',plugins_url('public/css/style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'contact-custom-style');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jsforcon-frontend-js', plugins_url('includes/submit-form.js', __FILE__),array(),false,true  );
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'wpforajax_con_test', plugins_url('public/js/test.js', __FILE__) );
    // wp_register_script('wpforajax_con_test', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'test.js', true);

    wp_localize_script(
        'jsforcon-frontend-js',
        'jsforcon_globals',
        [
          'ajax_url'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
          'nonce'       => wp_create_nonce( 'jsforcon_insert_nonce' )
        ]
      );
}
```

And change `jsforwp_globals.ajax_url` to `jsforcon_globals.ajax_url`

```
var cf_saveContact =  document.getElementById("cf_saveContact");
cf_saveContact.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var conName =  document.getElementById("conName").value;
    var conMail =  document.getElementById("conMail").value;
    var conContant =  document.getElementById("conContant").value;
   
    if(conName == "" || conMail == "" || conContant == ""){
        document.querySelector(".con_error_msg").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>all fields are required</p>";
    }else{
        var action = "jsforcon-insert";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET",jsforcon_globals.ajax_url+"?action="+action+"&_ajax_nonce="+jsforcon_globals.nonce+"&name="+conName+"&mail="+conMail+"&content="+conContant,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                conName =  document.getElementById("conName").value = "";
                conMail =  document.getElementById("conMail").value = "";
                conContant =  document.getElementById("conContant").value = "";
                document.querySelector(".con_error_msg").innerHTML = "<p style='color:green'>Successfully Sent</p>";
            } 
        } 
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you're doing this in an AJAX call? Are you writing out the response from the AJAX call to be sure that you're not getting errors? Always check the XMLHttpRequest's status and response for errors before proceeding.